# 2 addresses combining after checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, shipping-address

Version Magento 2.4.5-p2

I have 20 plus orders in the last few months that the shipping address is incorrect after the order is placed. Talking with affected customers, they are positive the screen is displaying the addresses correctly before they click "Place Order".  I've been tracking the order details to see if I can identify a pattern with the sequence of steps or payment method, but have yet to find one.  Looking for assistance to help resolve.

Most common scenarios:

- Address Line 1 of existing additional address, city/state of default billing/shipping
- Address line 1 of default bill/ship,  city/state of new unsaved additional address

The above has happened with a keyed credit card or using a vaulted stored card.  Issues have been reported using Chrome, Edge, Safari browsers, mobile and laptop devices.

Some users have indicated that they have used an address autofill on our site, but that doesn't explain the why an order shipped to a previously stored address is mashed.

1. In all cases, the Billing and Shipping address are different.
2. With a keyed card, I've tried checking the billing/shipping checkbox, then going back to the shipping step to select an address (or add a brand new address), then going back to the payment page to complete checkout.
3. In the quote table, we can see the address mismashed on some orders.

Any input on tables/fields to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your issue, I'm getting the same problem on my end.

Comment: Unfortunately, no we have not found a solution.  It is still happening sporadically.   We have 2 working theories:  1. Autofill on the person's browser is somehow affecting.  2. The bill/ship checkbox in the quote table is somehow getting set when it should not be.